# Concat specific fields separated by space(s)

Tags: text-processing, command-line, text-formatting

I have a string that is separated by spaces and I need to get concated the 2nd and 3rd “word”/field making sure that if more than one space separates the words/fields it is handled properly.
The following works fine:

```
tr -s " " |cut -d ' ' -f2 -f3 | tr " " "-"
```

I was wondering is there an even more succinct way of doing this?

Comment: Why not just `awk '{printf "%s-%s\n", $2, $3}'`?

Comment: Can you provide a sample string and an expected output?

Comment: @Inian:`1234 George Jones 56789` -> `George-Jones`

Comment: @Jim: See the first comment from cuonglm, that should work. And its a too trivial question to ask

Comment: @cuonglm: Does this handle multiple whitespaces between fields well?

Comment: @Inian: I was wondering if I could do it without using another tool

Comment: "Does this handle multiple whitespaces between fields well?" Just test it. `echo '1234    George            Jones 56789' |awk '{printf "%s-%s\n", $2, $3}'`. Ugh, whitespace was gobbled in the comment. But just add multiple whitespace and test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` will by default use any number of whitespaces as the field separator, so your issue could be solved by the single `awk` invocation

```
awk '{ printf("%s-%s\n", $2, $3) }'
```

with the data passed to the standard input of `awk`.

Doing the same thing in the shell (which also, by default, will split the input on whitespaces in pretty much the same way as `awk` does):

```
read -r number first second therest
printf '%s-%s\n' "$first" "$second"
```

with the data passed to the standard input of `read`.

If you want to only use `tr` and `cut`, I believe you already have the most compact solution for that.

Comment: +1 for not answering in the comments… Also, for the sake of having a formal source, the man page says `The awk utility shall interpret each input record as a sequence of fields where, by default, a field is a string of non-<blank> non-<newline> characters.`

Comment: I was wondering if the tools I already used could also have solved what I need or using awk is the only alternative

Comment: @Jim I don't think it can be made more efficient than what you already have if you want to use only `tr` and `cut`.